# Tomcat: war deployed using ANT is not reachable

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, intellij-idea

I have two applications deployed in Tomcat server. Both are same just there names are changed. App2 is working as expected and is reachable but app1 is not, it gives error 404 not found on accessing.

I have deployed them by different means:

app1 - is deployed using ANT. I created the war file then copied it to webapps folder of tomcat

app2 - I created this from Intellij IDE and deployed using Tomcat manager UI page.

app2 shows session 1 and app1 showing session as 0.

i am not sure what to check , any suggestions. There are no error msg in tomcat server log

Comment: 505 does *not* mean 'not reachable'.

Comment: Check your web.xml in App2 application check the welcome url is correct than run your application and check it.

Comment: @EJP ... status corrected

Comment: @vicky ..tx buddy already tried all this but tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about going to the webapp directory and compare app1 and app2 directories to see what the difference is? If the contents of app1 and app2 are too different to do this you could try deploying app2 into, say app3, using ANT and check out the difference, if any!

Comment: thnaks, i made few changes ... i copied the structure as was in working app ....  its working now!!